# 'Access token is invalid' error in spreadsheet library php

Tags: php, cakephp, google-sheets

I need to upload spreadsheet via google drive in cakephp.I am using [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php) to generate access token and [php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) to access the sheets.Code is as follows:

```
function test() {
    require_once '../vendors/google-api-php-client-2.1.1/vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("spreadsheet");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("//My developerkey");
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('client_id.json');
    if( !isset($_GET['code']) ) {

        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
        $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/test' );
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    } else {

        $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/test' );
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
        $client->setAccessToken($token);

        $serviceRequest = new Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest($token['access_token']);
        Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);
        $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
        $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();
        $spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('Test');
    }
```

But I get the error that access token is invalid as shown in following image:

[image]

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: @johan doe, you may have a look https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1157

Answer (score 1):

Hi this might will help , first please create your developer accout on google and generate access token client id etc. Then follow this steps.

Prerequisites

To run this quickstart, you'll need:

**PHP 5.4 or greater with the command-line interface (CLI) and JSON extension installed.
    The Composer dependency management tool.
    Access to the internet and a web browser.
    A Google account.**

**Step 1: Turn on the Google Sheets API**

Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and automatically turn on the API. Click Continue, then Go to credentials.
On the Add credentials to your project page, click the Cancel button.
At the top of the page, select the OAuth consent screen tab. Select an Email address, enter a Product name if not already set, and click the Save button.
Select the Credentials tab, click the Create credentials button and select OAuth client ID.
Select the application type Other, enter the name "Google Sheets API Quickstart", and click the Create button.
Click OK to dismiss the resulting dialog.
Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the client ID.
Move this file to your working directory and rename it client_secret.json.

**Step 2: Install the Google Client Library**

Run the following command to install the library using composer:

```
php composer.phar require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

See the library's installation page for the alternative installation options.
**Step 3: Set up the sample**

Create a file named quickstart.php in your working directory and copy in the following code:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

// Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
$spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

if (count($values) == 0) {
  print "No data found.\n";
} else {
  print "Name, Major:\n";
  foreach ($values as $row) {
    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
    printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
  }
}
```

**Step 4: Run the sample**

Run the sample using the following command:

```
php quickstart.php
```

The first time you run the sample, it will prompt you to authorize access:

```
Browse to the provided URL in your web browser.

If you are not already logged into your Google account, you will be prompted to log in. If you are logged into multiple Google accounts, you will be asked to select one account to use for the authorization.
Click the Accept button.
Copy the code you're given, paste it into the command-line prompt, and press Enter.
```

[More about google sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)

Answer (score 0):

After facing of lot of issues with Google spreadsheet i finally did this. In your developer console  create web_service account and download its credentials in .json format which looks similar to

```
{
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "rank********er",
      "private_key_id": "*****************************",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nkey here\n",
      "client_email": "rank***@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "1066978********************",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/ra*******r%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
```

Then in your class / file where you want to use google spreadsheet use this code. Before using spreadsheet you need to share that sheet  to client-email given in json file.

```
<?php
include dirname(__DIR__) . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

$credential = dirname(__FILE__) . "/client_secret.json";
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $credential);
$client = new \Google_Client;
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$client->setApplicationName("Some App");
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'
    ]);

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()["access_token"];

$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('Spreadsheet Name');
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getWorksheetFeed()->getEntries()[0];

$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();
$cellFeed = $worksheet->getCellFeed();
$entries = $listFeed->getEntries();

foreach ($listFeed->getEntries() as $entry) {
    $proxy = $entry->getValues();
    $proxy['status'] = $status_message;
    $entry->update($proxy);
}
```

Change the Title / App name as per yours. You can install the below libraries via composer to use the above lines of code.

```
"google/apiclient":"^2.0",
"asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client": "3.0.*",
```

For reference use : https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client

Comment: In the code where will I be prompted to choose a google account to read the spreadsheet from?

Comment: I am talking about a google account prompt like http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2363873/9aba733d47e63321d02f0368baa3df3e

Comment: I don't need to access my data but the client's data who has given access to his google account's data.